# Taylor expansion for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I don't understand how to expand this function, for example how do I plug $x=0$ into $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ ? All derivatives of the function have $x$ in the denominator, I'm just confused.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even if you can't evaluate it (or derivatives) at $x=0$, do you know how to take the limit as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: Another possibility is to just expand $\sin$ by itself, then divide the answer by $x$...

Comment: Why do you need to taylor expansion for this fraction? You cannot use taylor expansion to find the limit

Comment: @imranfat I'm trying to find the Taylor expansion of Si(x).

Comment: @MarkEmacr , Ah, I see...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor Series for $\sin x$ is as follows :

$$x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...}{x}$$
$$ = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!}...$$
At $x=0$ all the terms with $x$ are $0$ and we are left with only $1$.